# In python, how can I be notified when another thread is started(alive) and avoid busy waiting

Tags: python, multithreading, signals

I am in this scenario: at a certain point, the main thread need to wait until another thread is started(alive). How can I notify the main thread?

I do not want to write a loop and keep the main thread busy waiting. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `threading.Semaphore` where your main thread will call `acquire` after calling start on the second thread. When the second thread is started to the point you want it will call `release` on the same semaphore.

If the second thread calls `release` first then the main thread will return from the `acquire` immediately. If the main thread calls `acquire` first then it will block until the second thread calls `release`.

---

Use `threading.Condition` where a single condition variable is made available to the main thread and the second thread. The main thread can then `wait` on the variable after it has started the second thread. When the second thread is up it can change the variable and then issue a `notify` on it.